# Problem with pattern regex in Watson's entity

Tags: regex, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, regex-group, watson-assistant

Greetings.

I need Watson to recognize an entity that represents the branch of our Company that the Customer has placed an order with. We currently use the following pattern on the customer_branch entity:

```
\d{1,5}-[xX\d]{1}
```

The dialog node asks the Customer's branch, with the following message: "Please, enter the branch's number where you placed the order, in this pattern XXXXX-X:", expecting something like:

> 12345-6

Although most of our Customers type the branch number correctly, some do:

> branch 12345-6
>
> nr 12345-6
>
> nr. 12345-6
>
> number 12345-6

This causes Watson not to recognize the entity customer_branch, frustrating them. To solve the problem, we thought about using the following regex in the pattern:

```
(?:(br[ae]{1}nch|n[umbe]{0,4}r))?(?:[\s.]*)?(\d{1,5}-[xX\d]{1})
```

The logic we think is as follows:

- a regex group to ignore any word like "branch", "number", "nr." and
  so on, that can or cann't be present;
- another to ignore periods and
  spaces in any quantity, that can or cann't be present;
- and finally
  one to capture the branch number.

However, after some tests we are did, Watson still does not recognize the entity correctly, as in the example below:

```
"customer_branch": "nr 12345-6"
```

We assume that the problem is in the regex, but we were unable to identify it; as it works correctly on regex101.com. Does Watson recognizes correctly exclusion regex groups like `(?: Something_here)`? We appreciate any tips. Thank all you.

Comment: If you are using English language, you could move to annotated entities.The regex engine is loosely based on the Java engine: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-patterns

Comment: Dear data_henrik, greetings. My native language is Portuguese-BR. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to capture the entire user input and then use the [string functions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-strings) to extract the number. You could use first a search (contains) for branch, then a [ternary operator](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response) to switch depending on the result.

IMHO pattern-based entities work for some precise input, but if you allow too many variations it is hard to capture it with a single pattern.

Have you tried creating multiple patterns for a single entity? Each value can have its own pattern assigned. That way you could have **customer_branch** as entity and **number_only** and **branch_number** as values.

Comment: data_henrik, thanks for your answer. We will try it.